# hitTestPoint() shapeFlag not working on movieClip containing loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a .swf file containing a circle that I load from a URL, make into a movieClip and add it to the stage.

I would like to be able to detect when the user places the cursor over the circle. I'd like it to be accurate in a sense that it doesn't simply use the bounding box of the circle, but the actual circle itself to detect a collision. This is a fragment of my current code:

```
    //
    var myCircle:MyCircle = new MyCircle(swf);
    myCircle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
    myContainer.addChild(myCircle);
    //

    private function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var glowFilter:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
        glowFilter.color = 0xffffff;
        if (event.currentTarget is MyCircle) {
            var object:MyCircle = event.currentTarget as MyCircle;
            if(object.hitTestPoint(event.stageX, event.stageY, true))
                event.currentTarget.filters = [glowFilter]; 
            else
                event.currentTarget.filters = []; 
        }
    }
```

I was led to believe that the `shapeFlag` parameter to the `hitTestPoint()` method would do this, but setting it either true or false makes no difference. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: May be loaded circle contains opacity layers?

Comment: thanks I've checked and it's not this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very short blog post about this earlier so I had it for future times...

It seems like you are looking at stageX which AFAIK is the global x-coordinate of the object.

http://messer1024.blogspot.se/2012/06/proper-hittest-in-as3.html

Short version of a short post:

After many ugly attempts at handling hit tests in AS3 I finally managed to solve what I was looking for. The thing I forgot to consider was to use the global mouse-coordinates.

```
public function hitTestMouse(hitarea:DisplayObject):Boolean {
    return hitarea.hitTestPoint(hitarea.stage.mouseX, hitarea.stage.mouseY, true);
}
```

The last parameter (shapeFlag) would decide if the hit test are checked any actual shapes inside the hitarea that the mouse is hovering above.

---

So in order for your thing to work, you should probably make it a bit easier and add my function and then run "hitTestMouse(myCircle)" when you feel like testing it